# How to add mouse hover on table columns in pug?

Tags: css, angularjs, pug

I am using angularjs and pug for the front end. I want to display different text on mouse hover on 7 columns like Yesterday, 2 days ago, 3 days ago, .... 7 days ago.

My table is

`tbody
    tr
      td.text-center(ng-repeat="value in collection track by $index") {{value}}`

I don't want to use separate CSS file. All required styles should be in pug file itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
style(type="text/css").
  td .org {
    display: inline;
  }

  td .hover{
    display:none;
  }

  td:hover .org {
    display: none;
  }

  td:hover .hover{
    display: inline;
  }

  tbody
  tr
    td.text-center(ng-repeat="value in collection track by $index") 
      span.org {{value}}
      span.hover Yester / 2 days ago / 3 days ago .....
```